# How to make search engines crawl tens of thousands of pages in my website

Tags: asp.net, seo, search-engine, google-crawlers

I have a large amount of items that each item has a page like this site/item_show.aspx?id=The_ID_here there are tens of thousands of items and each day nearly two thousands are added. Furthermore each item has a description in its page so for each item, its page should be crawled by search engines.

My question is with this amount of data described: How can I generate sitemaps or anything like that to make all items visible by google and other search engines?

It is clear that I cannot show all items in the first pages but I can make pages that simply just contains the link of items and provide tens of them each page for just search engine. Would it work or is it anything better to do for making items be indexed by google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

essentially there are 3 methods which will help you with the Mass-Indexing :
1. Create an XML SiteMap for all of your pages and link to it from you HomePage.
2. you should have Google Webmaster Tools Installed and you can load that same XML file into it.
3. Have an Organized Categories structure - depending on the type of your site think about a logical Categories Structure for example in eCommerce stores all the products are categorized by product Main-Category then a product Sub-category and sometimes by Brands etc... - of course you should do this via your Shopping-cart platform - Just remember that if you begin chaging the URLs-structure you'll need to take care of all the Redirects from the old URLS to the new ones.

Comment: If each day 2000 URLs are added, the site should definitely have more than 1 XML sitemap. Once you cross 10k URLs you most definitely should create a new sitemap

Answer (score -1):

First, use XML sitemaps and submit those to Google (note that i said sitemapS - more than one).

Next, ensure that your on-site content is nicely organised into categories and sub-categories - ideally you'd want all elements to be reachable in as few clicks as possible without users (or Googlebot) having to resort to the search function.

Finally, ensure that your more popular / important items are featured in the homepage or 1-2 clicks deep, and get links and social shares to those specific product pages.

Answer (score -1):

Be popular and get links to your site. Have a good server which can handle the crawl.

> There is also not a hard limit on our crawl. The best way to think
>   about it is that the number of pages that we crawl is roughly
>   proportional to your PageRank. So if you have a lot of incoming links
>   on your root page, we’ll definitely crawl that. Then your root page
>   may link to other pages, and those will get PageRank and we’ll crawl
>   those as well. As you get deeper and deeper in your site, however,
>   PageRank tends to decline...

https://www.stonetemple.com/matt-cutts-interviewed-by-eric-enge-2/